# UITextFiled and UILabel layout failed with Masonry

Tags: ios, objective-c, masonry

The structure is a view with a label and a textfield inside.
I need to adapt different device with different font size in a label, and textfield's width is flexible according to label's width.

code below:

```
    UIView *selectBgView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectBgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [condiView addSubview:selectBgView];
    [selectBgView makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.equalTo(@200);
        make.height.equalTo(@20);
        make.left.equalTo(@10);
        make.top.equalTo(@20);
    }];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    label.text = @"Type :";
    [condiView addSubview:label];
    [label makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.top.bottom.equalTo(selectBgView);
    }];

    UITextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    [condiView addSubview:textField];
    [textField makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.right.top.bottom.equalTo(selectBgView);
        make.left.equalTo(label.right);
    }];
```

It doesn't work like picture below.

[image]

But when I exchange the textfield with a view. It works!

[image]

```
    UIView *view = [UIView new];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [condiView addSubview:view];
    [view makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.right.top.bottom.equalTo(selectBgView);
        make.left.equalTo(label.right);
    }];
```

If anyone could help me out! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I use the storyboard and set the same constants, It works well...

Comment: How about code? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your label doesn't specify a width so it is only as wide as it needs to be. Views work differently because they aren't sizing to fit content. Try and specify a width for your text field or pin it to the right side with an offset.

Comment: So the label without width contraint should be it as wide as it needs to be.It seem not like that when the label shows with a text field behind it, but a view. I have pinned the text field like 'make.right.equalTo(selectBgView)'.Is that not enough? Thanks for your answer.@Bill Burgess